# WP_REST_Response vs WP_Error

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

I'm a bit confused about how errors are handled in Wordpress's REST API. In their examples, they suggest using `WP_Error` to return errors, but `WP_REST_Response` has the HTTP status code as a second parameter, which makes it shorter and somewhat cleaner to my taste.

So I'm comparing this way of returning an error:

```
return new WP_REST_Response(array('error' => 'Error message.'), 400);
```

With this one:

```
return new WP_Error('rest_custom_error', 'Error message.', array('status' => 400));
```

With the first option, I can have just the error text in my response and it's enough for me. So the response would look like so:

> {"error":"Error message."}

With the second one it's more detailed:

> {"code":"rest_custom_error","message":"Error message.","data":{"status":403}}

But I also need to specify the error code (first parameter), which doesn't give any advantage to my front-end implementation. Other than the syntax, I'm curious about differences in performance, security and future-proof factors.

So is there any reason to prefer one over the other than personal preferences?

Comment: This confuses me too. Have you resolved it?

Comment: It probably has to do with how WP is treating the responses. Just use the second variant.

Answer (score 8):

I do as follows:

```
WP_REST_Response // Used when endpoint code runs just fine but needs to 
                 // tell the client about some other downstream error (e.g. 4xx)
```

```
WP_Error // Used when endpoint code has an issue and needs to tell you
         // it didn't compute or couldn't find resources etc (e.g. 5xx)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, WordPress changes the status codes of the responses in unpredictable ways. This is dumb. For instance, if you create a WP_REST_RESPONSE with status 400, it actually sends it as status 200 with "status:400" as data in the body.

What I do:
Just use PHP response functions:

```
http_response_code(400);
exit;
```

If you tell me I'm wrong, please explain the benefit of using these two function wrappers. I see the benefit if you work for Automattic and are creating regressions in core itself. If you're a plugin or theme dev, [and you're assuming core works] these functions should be avoided as having no use.

Comment: To return the right response code, just do : 

`return new WP_REST_Response(array(), 400);`

If I check in the DevTools, I see a "400 Bad Request". So it works.

Comment: Not sure if this was true in the past, but I just tested returning `new WP_REST_Response(array(), 400);` from an endpoint the HTTP code is set correctly. Tested making a request with `curl -I`